# Different view from viewport than the render

Tags: rendering, materials, 3d-view, light

I am a beginner in a blender and this is my first model. I have a problem because the final render is not the same as rendering the viewport. I do not know if this is a problem with the rendering settings or the model. I add screenshots and file.

And sorry for my english, im from Poland and still practicing.

View from viewport:

[image]

Render:

[image]

File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b76DHKwo7jI0lJFjp9LYZqWLeJivarTh

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Please use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to share your .blend. Once uploaded there, you'll be given a link to paste into your question. To do so, click the [edit] link below the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

For the bottle you have different levels of subdivision (1 for preview, and 2 for render). That gives the inconsistency.

Comment: I was changing subdivision settings in many different ways and applied on model, and nothing got better.

Comment: Ok, sorry after restart render view i see flatter render. But how to get the result from the earlier viewport :/

Comment: We all have your old blend file as a backup. :-)  So it's easy to roll back. As for differences, maybe your solidify modifier. It's disabled for preview, but enabled for render. (those little eye and camera icons).